# Полный перезапуск приложения с убиванием процессов

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, делаю полный перезапуск приложения с убиванием всех процессов, почему не вызывается метод onDestroy() перед закрытием из активити? 
Можно ли как-то вызвать в данном случае, как вообще делается, может какую строку кода или флаг где добавить надо?

```
//полный перезапуск с убиванием процессов
            Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    PackageManager packageManager = mapsActivity.getPackageManager();
                    Intent intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(mapsActivity.getPackageName());
                    ComponentName componentName = intent.getComponent();
                    Intent mainIntent = Intent.makeRestartActivityTask(componentName);
                    mapsActivity.startActivity(mainIntent);
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
                }
            }, 5);
```

Comment: Как по-вашему может быть выполнен какой-то код, когда процесс уже мёртв? Остановка процесса - это немедленное прекращение выполнения приложения и выгрузка его из памяти. Если вам нужно выполнить какой-то код перед остановкой процесса, то вызывайте его вручную, а уж после `exit()`.

Answer (score 0):

Вы завершаете приложение до вызова метода `onDestroy()`.
Можно попробывать перезапустить вот так:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Intent i = mapsActivity.getBaseContext()
                                .getPackageManager()
                                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(mapsActivity.getBaseContext().getPackageName());

                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                }, 5);
```